# render html in flex 4 (web) without an iframe

Tags: apache-flex, flex4

I know this question was asked before, but none of the solutions work properly.
How do I render a basic html in flex 4 without an iframe? I saw textarea renders some weird format that would suffice if it would work.

For example I wan't to add an image like this

```
text_area.htmlText += "<img src='...' />";
```

then 1. I press enter 2. I add the image again like above, I get the img tag inserted 10 times or so; which is weird (but not funny at all). All things being equal, html is a much normal approach, is there a basic renderer for flex 4 that works ok? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll want to use either `RichText` or `RichEditableText` component to show your html using TLF.  You'll want to do something like this:

```
<s:RichText textFlow="{TextConverter.importToFlow(yourHtmlString, TextConverter.TEXT_FIELD_HTML_FORMAT)}" />
```

However, you should know that if you have a lot of html, the conversion is going to take longer.

Comment: Beat me to it!  It's worth noting that there's only a subset of HTML tags supported, full list available here:  http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flashx/textLayout/conversion/TextConverter.html#TEXT_FIELD_HTML_FORMAT

Comment: Thanks for the helpful link Marty :)